# Alternative to using `getByTestId()` in React-testing-library

Tags: create-react-app, react-testing-library

I am currently using `getByTestId()` for a test in my React app. The test looks like this:

```
it('should be truthy when clicking to play or pause if "hasVideo" is true', () => {
  const newProps = {
    hasVideo: true
  }
  render(<VideoCardForm {...newProps} />);
  const videoEl = screen.getByTestId('video-play-pause');
  const result = fireEvent.click(videoEl);
  expect(result).toBeTruthy(); 
});
```

And the relevant DOM section looks like this:

```
<video
  data-testid="video-play-pause"
  className={this.state.isPlaying ? classes.VideoOnPlay : classes.VideoPrep }
  onClick={(event) => {
    this.onVideoClick(this.props.url, event);
  }}
  src={`${this.props.url}`}
>
</video>
```

This works. But it seems hacky to me to add something to the DOM like this: `data-testid`, solely for the purpose of running a test. Is there an alternative I could add to the DOM, that actually serves a semantic purpose beyond just allowing for the running of a test?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DOM through render itself in container property.

`const { container } = render(...)`.

If video is the nested DOM you can always use `container.querySelector('video')` to get the video DOM.

Comment: So, while this makes the test past, it will not work when I change my props. In other words, when the test should fail, it doesn't. So, structured like this, it's not a useful test. Note that the test would fail when expected when I assigned a `testid`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to check if the class is getting applied properly when prop changes right. In that case you should change the test a little bit to expect the change of class applied on DOM when prop changes.